# Zend Mail Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, email, gmail

Hi I'm trying to send some emails via gmail from the Zend_Mail module. 
This is my code:

```
$config = array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',
    'port' => 587,
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => 'webmaster@mydomain.com',
    'password' => 'password'
);
$smtpConnection = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
```

Error:

*Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto() [streams.crypto]: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php on line 206
Unable to connect via TLS*

I tried telling my hosting provider to enable the openssl.dll in phi.ini

But they say that isn't necessary since the server is in Linux and it doesn't need to enable the openssl.dll to work with TLS or SSL.

Is my hosting provider wrong or I'm I doing something wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance

Fabian

Answer (score 12):

openssl.dll is the windows openssl extension.

On Linux you need to compile PHP with OpenSSL support. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

You need OpenSSL for PHP sockets and stream functions to use TLS. Zend uses these functions and thus require the same.

Comment: How would I know in phpinfo if Openssl is enabled? All I see is this  OpenSSL/0.9.8b in the apache2handler

Comment: You actually need two things, OpenSSL and TLS should be registered as a stream/socket transport. 

This should be found under: Registered Stream Socket Transports

The OpenSSL should be found under it's own header since it is an enabled extension. The apache2handler shows the apache config, not PHP's. So you do have OpenSSL compiled on your server and apache configured to use it, but you probably don't have the OpenSSL PHP extensions compiled with PHP.  

Search your PHP.ini for OpenSSL and see if you find it.

Comment: Yeah I only have: 
Registered Stream Socket Transports  tcp, udp, unix, udg and no header for the OpenSSL.

SO I guess the problem was all on my hosting provider side.

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to ask your host to recompile PHP with OpenSSL support. OpenSSL is a bit of a pain since PHP can't load the extension at runtime, it needs it compiled with the binary.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar problem here is what worked;
Using Zend  mail transport and yahoo smtp:

```
$mailhost= 'smtp.example.com';
$mailconfig = array(
    'auth'     => 'login',
    'username' => 'me@example.com',
    'password' => 'topsecret',
    'port'     => '465',
    'ssl'      => 'ssl'
);
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Smtp($mailhost, $mailconfig);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```

This produced an error: "Permission denied" and no mail was sent. After three weeks of trying all solutions I could find the one that worked was changing:
$transport to;
`$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail('-fsupport@website.com',$mailhost, $mailconfig);`

works as expected...

Comment: Finally the right answer! It wasn't the settings themselves per se, but the fact that using Zend_Mail_Smtp doesn't work with gmail, while Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail does.

Answer (score 2):

It's very comfortably to use [Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport](http://snowcore.net/zend_mail-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-gmail) method

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ssl:// as prefix for the hostname and use 465 as port.

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have 
smtp.server = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
and port 465

Answer (score 0):

after hours of troubleshooting, changing
'ssl' => 'tls'
to
'ssl' => 'ssl'

worked for me. It was working fine in previous server. After moving to new server, tls error statrted.