# Send mail with Zend_Mail through Gmail smtp server

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, gmail, zend-mail

I'd like to use **Gmail** smtp server to send email with **Zend_Mail**. I had this code

```
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport(new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp("smtp.googlemail.com", array(
    "auth" => "login",
    "username" => "myusername@gmail.com",
    "password" => "mypassword",
    "ssl" => "ssl",
    "port" => 465
)));
```

but when I try to send an email it throws an Exception with message **Connection refused**.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Not sure your params are ok. Check similar questions, e.g. this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094137/zend-mail-gmail-smtp) or others.

Answer (score 10):

Your params are wrong. Give it a shot with these:

```
$config = array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',
    'port' => 587,
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => 'myusername@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'mypassword'
);
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```