# Cannot send mail to yahoo (any address) using PHP code and SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, yahoo

I have the following code which sets up the SMTP server:

```
ini_set("send_from", "test@gmail.com");
ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

and i create a simple mail in this way:

```
mail("test@yahoo.com", "A subject", "My message for you", "From: TEST");
```

When I run this code, it fails to send mail to **Yahoo** e.g. **some.email@yahoo.com**. But when i use any **Gmail** mail address as the first argument, it works.

What's wrong ?

Comment: have you set the `smtp port` also? and username and password for `test@gmail.com`?

Comment: Do you require an SSL connection?

Comment: the problem is with yahoo not gmail

Comment: If I send from gmail to gmail then will work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In thi case you dont auth (user name passwort) and dont usw tls. This wont be accepted.

Better use this:

[XAMPP Sendmail using Gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948687/xampp-sendmail-using-gmail-account)

or an framework to send emails via smtp like

[Zend Mail Gmail SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094137/zend-mail-gmail-smtp)

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.sending.html

Here a code example

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest#ZF1

```
require('Zend/Mail.php');

$config = array(
    'ssl' => 'tls',
    'port' => 587,
    'auth' => 'login',
    'username' => 'your_gmail_address@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'password'
);
$smtpConnection = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($smtpConnection);

Zend_Mail::setDefaultFrom('your_gmail_address@gmail.com', 'Your real name');

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('any_address@yahoo.com', 'Test');

$mail->setSubject(
        'Demonstration - Sending Mails per SMTP Connection'
    );

$mail->setBodyText('...Your message here...');

$mail->send($smtpConnection);
```

Comment: how to setup on server ? I have no access to these details, to php.ini

Comment: Use the second example! What kind of server is it? Linux or Windows?

Comment: Then this makes no sense "ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.gmail.com");" and if ther normal mail wont work, your providers mailserver configuration is wrong and you have to use something like zend framework to send mails via smtp.

Comment: that is the problem, i have no error, everything seems ok but the mail is not arrived to yahoo server

Comment: But in gmail is your Mail within the out Box? What happens when you send the mail via gmail webmail?

Comment: Well, the mails come today ! After 4 days ... strange behaviour

Answer (score 1):

To send mail as an authenticated user you should **use email authentication methods** like [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), [DKIM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM) etc.

Also you need to make sure your domain should point to your IP address and IP address MUST point to same domain. This is called [Reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

Other good practice that prevents mails from going into spam folder are

1. Make sure you have a unsubscribe link
2. Make sure the `Reply-To` header is added and the email used here is a valid email.
3. Add a Name in the `To` field. Like `First Last <email@example.com>`
4. Add a postal address of the company you are mailing from which must include a phone number.

There was a form to white list email senders IP for yahoo. Now I dont find it. So try the above things, It should work well.

Comment: The mail never arrives to yahoo, it looks that yahoo reject automatically mails...I don't know why !

Comment: Could you send a mail manually by loging in into your gmail account? If that is not delivered its surely a yahoo problem and you need to report it.

Comment: Also your IP could be blacklisted!

Comment: my ip is not blacklisted ... i sent manually from my gmail to yahoo and works fine

Comment: If sending manually works. Then try setup those email authentication method.